# wordpress add_submenu_page adds broken link

Tags: plugin-development, menus

I install my plugin in several sites and the submenu links generation at backed works fine, but fails in one specific site.

I use the follow code to add the submenu items:

```
add_menu_page(
    'Plugin name',
    'Plugin name',
    'manage_options',
    basename(__FILE__),
    'handle_this_action'
);

add_submenu_page(
    basename(__FILE__),
    'Link 1',
    'Link 1',
    'manage_options',
    basename(__FILE__),
    'handle_this_action'
);
```

This will generate a menu box at backed with one link inside and the main link in the title of menu box. When I click on the main link at menu box I get correctly redirected to my page with a URL like follow:

**http://mysite.net/wp-admin/admin.php?page=myplugin.php**

But when I click on the submenu link I'm wrongly redirected to:

**http://mysite.net/wp-admin/myplugin.php?page=myplugin.php**

Instead of: **http://mysite.net/wp-admin/admin.php?page=myplugin.php**

I really don't know what I have to check in order to figure this out. The WordPress version used in the site that gives me this problem is Version 3.3.1 and I haven't any other plugin activated.

How I can proceed?
Any tip or help will be appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you use...say `'my_test_string'` instead of `basename(__FILE__)` for your slug?

Comment: I'm not sure if this can cause the problem, but you don't need `basename()` function, just use `__FILE__`.

Comment: m0r7if3r: I did the change and the generated link is broken too (point to a non existing page), is http://mysite.net/wp-admin/myplugin.php?page=my_test_string

Comment: Mamaduka: Thank. I did the change and the problem disappears. In my local server works in both ways but in that installation only works if I put in the way you suggest. I really don't know why. If you put your reply as an answer I will select you.

Comment: maybe was the fact that I change the menu slug so WordPress reload some information about the menu?

Answer (score 3):

WordPress is doing exactly what you're *telling* it to do. Refer to the [Codex entry for `add_submenu_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page). The functions arguments are like so:

```
<?php 
add_submenu_page( 
    $parent_slug, 
    $page_title, 
    $menu_title, 
    $capability, 
    $menu_slug, 
    $function 
);
?>
```

So, you're assigning the same string to `$parent_slug` and `$menu_slug`. For obvious reasons, these two need to be different.

- `$parent_slug` is the slug of the *parent* menu page. You assign that as `basename( __FILE__ )` in your `add_menu_page()` call.
- `$menu_slug` is the slug of the *sub-menu* page. Note what the Codex says:

  > If you want to NOT duplicate the parent menu item, you need to set the name of the $menu_slug exactly the same as the parent slug.

While this statement is written confusingly, I think it's saying that by setting `$parent_slug` and `$menu_slug` the same, you're *replacing* the main-parent sub-menu entry with *this* page - and it sounds like that's *not* what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the questions indeed is why the second generated link is different than the first, because I want both be the same. Note that the second has myplugin.php?page=myplugin.php instead of admin.php?page=myplugin.php

Comment: Thanks!  I came here when I googled to see what the explanation of $menu_slug was trying to say.  Very confusingly written in the codex so glad of the help.